# Connect VGA monitor to modern GPU

Tags: hdmi, vga, dvi, displayport, adapter

I have an old LCD monitor that only has VGA input. The problem is that I just got a new GPU and it only supports DVI-D (digital only), HDMI, and DisplayPort.

I tried connecting my VGA cable to a small DVI-I adapter that I had at home, but my GPU only has DVI-D plus it is digital only, so I borrowed an active converter to DisplayPort. It's not working.

Why are the adapters/converters that I tried not working?
How can I connect my monitor to my GPU then?

Note: I will buy a modern monitor in two months I think... but until then I really want to use my new GPU.

Comment: What is an "active converter to display port"?

Comment: I am currently aware of adapters from DisplayPort graphics card to VGA: https://www.amazon.com/HP-AS615AA-Displayport-VGA-Adapter/dp/B0025ZUF8K and it doesn't need to be active. I only tested active HDMI to VGA adapters and I don't recommend them.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf: an active adapter means that you need to connect it to an AC power source.

Comment: @Alex - an active adapter **doesn't always require** an external AC power source.  It can be powered by a USB cable connected to a host USB device or not even require it in the case of devices powered by the DVI-D bus itself.  Your definition of an active adaptor in this case isn't accurate.

Comment: @Hori - If you want help we need more specific information.  If you want to know the reason your adaptor isn't work you should give us specifics.

Comment: So my monitor has VGA analog output only. My GPU has HDMI, DP and DVI-D dual-link digital only. I have a DP to DVI-I dual-link converter (AFAIK it is an active one because it does have a small circuit board inside) and also a small DVI-I dual-link to VGA adapter. I connected all those together. They fit, but the monitor is displaying black and the "no signal" message. My GPU unfortunately doesn't support any kind of analog output without a separate converter. May it be that the DP-DVI converter isn't actually converting the analog signal to digital?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to connect your monitor to the GPU is to buy a VGA to Display Port/DVI-D adapter. you could pick one up at almost any electronics store or order one from amazon or something.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. That looks like the answer to my question. However I decided to just go and buy a new monitor with HDMI cable. Adapters are like 20 euros here, for some reason, and I can get a Full HD LED monitor, that's much better than my current LCD 1440x900 VGA one, for around 100. And at least I will get to keep it as a secondary screen once I will buy a good primary one, the adapter would have been just temporary.